# Bizzare as.POSIXct error

Tags: r

I stubbled across what appears to be a odd error in the `as.POSXct` function in R associated with date/time of 2 am on March 9, 2014.

The following simple example shows the nature of the bug.

3 am works

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-Mar-09 03:00", format="%Y-%b-%d %H:%M")
[1] "2014-03-09 03:01:00 MDT"
```

2 am fails

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-Mar-09 02:00", format="%Y-%b-%d %H:%M")
[1] NA
```

Any time within 2 am fails

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-Mar-09 02:01", format="%Y-%b-%d %H:%M")
[1] NA
> as.POSIXct("2014-Mar-09 02:59", format="%Y-%b-%d %H:%M")
[1] NA
```

March 10, 2014 is fine

```
> as.POSIXct("2014-Mar-10 02:00", format="%Y-%b-%d %H:%M")
[1] "2014-03-10 02:00:00 PDT"
```

The original conversions specified the timezone (`tz='Canada/Mountain'`), which has been excluded for brevity. The same results were observed.  Adding non-existing seconds or changing the format (example `%I` for 12 hr time) didn't work either.

What is going on?  This is for R version 3.2.3 (OS X).

Comment: Try Googling "daylight savings time 2014". Those moments in time....NEVER HAPPENED! Duh duh duh!

Comment: Thanks to daylight savings time, some times simply do not exist.

Comment: @joran - paste your comment as an answer I will accept it.  I am befuddled why "professional" software is adding no-existing times to the log files

Comment: My general impression is that folks who write software that is heavily time/date dependent would say that it's sort of a miracle that dates/times work correctly on computers at all.

Comment: @joran - that's setting the bar rather low!

Comment: @MrFlick - I missed that duplicate question in my quick search, thank you for finding that existing thread.

Comment: I just mean that I have gathered that correctly implementing software to deal with dates/times in literally all cases becomes so unimaginably complex that it's sort of a miracle that even simple things work.